# TypeScript API for the Type checking of specific files?

Tags: typescript

This request is been frequently misunderstood (including the Google).
What I mean is running of the types checking for the specific TypeScript file by the Node.js API.
Usually it is been execute by the CLI, but I need the Node.js API.
It should be something like:

```js
import TypeScript from "typescript";


const typeScriptProgram: TypeScript.Program = TypeScript.createProgram(/*... */);

// [ Warning ] THIS IS THE DESIRED API, NOT EXISTING ONE
const typesCheckingResults: TypeScript.TypesCheckingResults = typeScriptProgram.checkTypes("foo.ts");

for (const issue of typesCheckingResults.issues) {
  console.log(issue.columnNumber)
  console.log(issue.lineNumber)
  console.log(issue.code) // Example: "TS2564"
  console.log(issue.message)
}
```

Comment: [This?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, Would you please to add the hash to link or mention the section?